# Pop functionality in stack server with OTP (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

In the book Programmers passport OTP by Bruce Tate there is the exercise to build a stack server similar to the example given by GenServer in their documentation but without the use of GenServer, i.e. with OTP functionality only. Implementing the pop functionality of the stack is the problem. This function (along with the push function of the stack) should be in the Core module and functions in this module are supposed to be reducers and free of side-effects. How am I able to implement pop as a call that returns the popped element to the client while having the necessary functionality in the core module and adhering to the rules of the core functions?

In the core module I first have what I wish to have:

```
defmodule Stack.Core do
  def pop([_head | tail]), do: tail
  ...
end
```

This function is a reducer and free of side-effects. However, the popped element (head) is not returned to the client. I then tried having this in the boundary layer:

```
defmodule Stack.Boundary do
  ...
  def run(state) do
    state
    |> listen()
    |> run()
  end

  def listen(state) do
    receive do
      {:pop, pid} ->
        [head | _tail] = state
        send(pid, {:pop, head})
        Core.pop(state)
    end
  end
end
```

But this has the same functionality as in the `Core.pop/1`, so `Core.pop/1` wouldn't even be necessary anymore. How does one implement pop in the stack and make it a call handle?

Comment: `pop/1` is usually implemented as `def pop([head | tail]), do: {head, tail}` in all known to me places. See `Map.pop/2`, `Keyword.pop/2` etc.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin that was an initial thought as well, but then the function is no longer a reducer.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what does “function is a reducer” mean. If you mean it can be passed as is to somewhat like `Enum.reduce/3`, then it should be of arity 2 in the first place.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I read too much into an example, but you are right, the core functions for an example in the book were meant to be reducers that could be passed into `Enum.reduce/3`.

Comment: Isn’t “reducer” word used as in https://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/05/introducing-reducees/ ?

Comment: I used "reducer" according to Bruce Tate: "The main functions in our core, those that do the bulk of the work, are reducers. These functions have a first argument of some type and return data of that same type." (Programmer Passport OTP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used “reducer” according to Bruce Tate: “The main functions in our core, those that do the bulk of the work, are reducers. These functions have a first argument of some type and return data of that same type.” ~ *Programmer Passport OTP*

That is the same definition as in https://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/05/introducing-reducees/

That means, we are after some generic function, accepting a list, and an actual *what-to-do-with-head* function and returning the reduced value back.

In our case, that would be *popping the value, calling a function on it, and returning the tail back*.

```elixir
defmodule Core do
  def pop([], _fun), do: raise "empty"
  def pop([head | tail], fun) do
    fun.(head)
    tail
  end
end
```

and use it like

```elixir
    receive do
      {:pop, pid} ->
        Core.pop(state, &send(pid, {:pop, &1}))
        # or Core.pop(state, fn h -> send(pid, {:pop, h}) end)
    end
```